# Import XML with jQuery: works on server, not locally

Tags: javascript, xml, jquery

I'm working on a script that reads an XML file and then outputs the data. It works perfectly when it runs on my web server, but won't run from my local machine. (The "542Data.xml" file is stored in the same folder as the HTML page on both the server and my computer, and I checked that all file versions are the same. I've tried it in Firefox and Chrome with the same results.)

```
<div id="output"></div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "542Data.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: parseXml
    });
});

function parseXml(xml)
{
    $(xml).find("point").each(function(index)
    {
        $("#output").append("Name: " + $(this).attr("name") + "<br />");
    });
}

</script>
```

The XML is structured as:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<destinations>
    <point name="Tot Lot at Bryan Park"> 
        <lat>39.15611</lat>
        <long>-86.52664</long>
        <type>outdoors</type>
    </point>
    <point name="Playground at Cascades Park"> 
        <lat>39.19633</lat>
        <long>-86.53581</long>
        <type>outdoors</type>
    </point>
</destinations>
```

What do I need to change to get this working locally?

**EDIT:** I was wrong, it's working in Firefox. (embarrassed!)

Comment: Do you mean file system locally or development server locally?

Comment: File system locally (e.g. file:\\\C:\Users\Erica\)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script works fine for me in Firefox.

Chrome has some security feature that disallows what you wanted to do (using `file:///` for AJAX requests). You need to start your browser with:

```
chrome --disable-web-security
```

to disable security checks. (`--allow-file-access-from-files` might also do the trick, but I haven't tested it yet)

**Warning:** disabling security checks affects your browser security and should only be used for *temporary* development purposes. If you plan to run the code from your local machine in a prolonged period of time, consider installing a web server on your local machine.

Comment: Yes it is security and not server related. That's the thing.

Comment: Yeah, it works in Firefox (and IE) for me now, too. I don't know what other quirk broke Firefox earlier, but it's gone now. Thanks for the additional info about getting Chrome to cooperate!

Answer (score 0):

If by "working locally" you mean you have the html and xml file in a folder and open the HTML file by double clicking on it, then there is no way.

In order for it to work locally you need an web server which will resolve http requests.  Opening a local file on a file system is not what is happening here.  `.ajax()` is making a server request.  Without a server it won't work.

Comment: ajax is not server obligatory! It is using a path and on the end on that path could be a server or just text file!

Comment: @AJbg - from http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ - "Perform an asynchronous HTTP (Ajax) request."  HTTP requires a server.  A browser **could** allow a URI -- but this is not to standard.

Comment: Yes when it comes to methods like POST and in this case is not a standart it is a request which is not POST and is pure get

Comment: I've no idea what you mean.  POST and GET are part of the HTTP standard.  http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.3

Comment: And http request is exactly what ajax does how you've managed 20k+

Answer (score 0):

What are you using to develop? Check if the development server you are using can serve XML files.

Comment: The guy wants to import and parse xml through jquery there aren't any server components needed for that to work.

Comment: There could be a server involved. He could be developing locally using Visual Studio, for example, and the development server could not be configured to serve XMLs (which it is, I am just using it to illustrate). It is not configured to serve icon files, or some video formats, for example.

Comment: This is completely differet

Answer (score 0):

According to the given (small) info. There is may be a security reason i.e. importing jquery from google's repository. Please give more code or look at the error console in firefox - ctr+shift+j and copy paste the error if there is any, or just download jquery and include it with path in local location.

Comment: Check that solution and include jquery locally

Answer (score 0):

It is running on server but not on your machine. See, the ajax request needs a local server running. To make it work, start some local server on your machine. For example, if you're on Windows, then download WAMP, and if on Linux, then install LAMP. Put your files in www folder. Then start the local server..and then access your file using localhost/your_file_name. That'll give you the result as you want it.