# jQuery External XML File Parsing - No data retrieve

Tags: jquery, xml

I have to parse `xml` rss file with with `jQuery` and set the background color according to that parsing color.But No data retrieve.

XML Rss File : colorsxml.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <channel name = "mycolors">
        <color1>RED</color1>
        <color2>BLUE</color2>
    </channel>
</root>
```

HTML Code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Color Replace</title>        
        <style type="text/css">
            body{
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            .box{
                float: left;
                display: block;
                width: 50%;
                height: 600px;                
            }  
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>            
        <div class="box box1">d</div>
        <div class="box box2">d</div>
        <script src="jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "colorsxml.xml",
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function(xml) {
                    // Parse the xml file and get data
                    var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml);
                            $xml = $(xmlDoc);
                    $color1 = $xml.find('channel[name="mycolors"] color1');
                    $color2 = $xml.find('channel[name="mycolors"] color2');
                    $(".box1").text($color1.text()+"HELLO"); // only for test
                    $(".box1").css("background-color", $color1.text());
                    $(".box2").css("background-color", $color2.text());
                }
            });
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check the implementation of the Backend. Does the backend retrieve the request?

Comment: Sorry,what did you mean "Backend" ?

Comment: Where is the xml-file? I mean it has to be somewhere. I thought you have the XML on a Server and try to retrieve it with an HTTP-GET-Request

Comment: XML file also in same directory.Look `Ajax` Function

Comment: So the XML-file is stored locally on your computer? Which Browser do you use? According to this it is not possible in all browsers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16003579/import-xml-with-jquery-works-on-server-not-locally

Comment: I am using Google Chrome

Comment: Already I used web server,same thing happened

Comment: Hm. I'm sorry, I can't reproduce the problem. If starting Chrome with `chrome --disable-web-security` doesn't help then I don't know a solution. Maybe someone else can reproduce the problem